# SSRS parameter not refreshing

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

I Having a problem getting query-based parameters to refresh in SSRS when the View Report or Refresh button is clicked.

First my data source from SSAS and i wanted to cascading between BU and GM.
So I have 2 dataset Param_BU and Param_GM

for Param_BU the code is

```
 WITH  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [BUSINESS
 UNIT].[Business Unit Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION  MEMBER
 [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [BUSINESS UNIT].[Business Unit
 Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME MEMBER 
 [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [BUSINESS UNIT].[Business Unit
 Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL  SELECT
 {[Measures].[ParameterCaption], [Measures].[ParameterValue],
 [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} ON COLUMNS  ,FILTER( [BUSINESS
 UNIT].[Business Unit
 Hierarchy].ALLMEMBERS,[Measures].[ParameterCaption]<>null) ON ROWS
 FROM [Model]
```

and for the dataset Param_GM

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [BUSINESS UNIT].[GM Area Desc].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [BUSINESS UNIT].[GM Area Desc].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [BUSINESS UNIT].[GM Area Desc].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL
SELECT {[Measures].[ParameterCaption], [Measures].[ParameterValue], [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} ON COLUMNS , 
[BUSINESS UNIT].[GM Area Desc].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM (select StrToSet(@Param_BU,Constrained) on columns from [Model])
```

I already set at Parameter on dataset Param_GM
but the there is an error said "The query contains the Param_BU parameter, which is not declared."

I already tried to closed the program and restart the computer, but nothing works.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the parameter matched up with the parameter in the Dataset Properties' **Parameters** tab?

[image]